# SDL not displaying anything to the window on Kubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, sdl, sdl-2

I'm making a program in C++ on Kubuntu and using SDL2 for graphics and displaying a window:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;

void initFullscreenWindow()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1920, 1080, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
}

void initWindowedWindow(int posX, int posY, int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_CreateWindow("Window", posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
}

void mainLoop()
{
    SDL_Event event;

    while(true)
    {
        SDL_Delay(1);

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 10, 26, 255);
        
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    SDL_Quit();
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    initFullscreenWindow();
    mainLoop();
}
```

...and it is just transparent and doesn't show anything.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Using your code, I can reproduce exactly what you describe. What is your expected output? In words, what shoult it look like other than blank?

Comment: Why don't you ever assign anything to `window` or `renderer`?

Comment: `SDL_CreateWindow()` and `SDL_CreateRenderer()` return pointers that you throw away leaving `window` and `renderer` as null pointers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm trying to have the background a different color and it not to be transparent

Comment: Re-try. I compiled your program and it had the effect I'd exptect.

Comment: I've compiled it over 10 times and it always doesn't show the effect